# Angular login with own Oauth2 provider

Tags: angularjs, oauth, oauth-2.0

I have created my own Oauth2 provider in rails and want to use it with angular.

At the moment if I make a call like this:

```
http://www.myservice.com/authenticate?callback="A PATH WHERE I WILL RECIEVE THE AUTH_TOKEN(example: localhost:8888/auth.html)"
```

I will be redirected to this url after authentication at my provider:

```
http://localhost:8888/auth.html?auth_token=8be580d851bcaa338d61fb494aac390f&token_expires=2014-03-19+17%3A22%3A55+UTC
```

I can then use the auth_token to make api-calls for one hour.

Is there an easy way to handle this with angular? I don't need super-security

Comment: Checkout a technique for that flow [here](http://weblogs.thinktecture.com/cweyer/2012/11/oauth2-in-thinktecture-identityserver-v2-implicit-grant-flow-with-javascript.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try

https://github.com/sahat/satellizer

it is a token-based AngularJS Authentication